# Слова «бараний», «тюлений», «свиной», «вороний» и др. Чем обосновывается написание одной «н»?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, прилагательные, нн

На одном из сайтов я нашёл такое объяснение:

> Прилагательные бараний, тюлений, свиной и подобные пишутся с одной н,
> так как они образованы от существительных с основой на н путем
> прибавления суффикса -j- (йот). Прилагательные пряный, румяный, юный
> пишутся с одной н, так как это непроизводные прилагательные.

Что значит «путём прибавления суффикса -j- (йот)»? Где в слове «бараний», «тюлений» и «свиной» суффикс -j- (йот)?

И вообще, правильно ли я понимаю, что эти прилагательные надо запомнить и их написание никак больше не обосновывается, кроме как правилом с -j- (йот)?

Answer (score 2):

Выбор Н или НН определяется путем анализа словообразования.

**1. Основа на Н и притяжательный суффикс ИЙ (одна буква Н)**

Тюлень – тюлен/ий, баран – баран/ий,  олень – олен/ий. Здесь суффикс ИЙ, а не Й (йота). При склонении Е – беглая, суффикс Й: тюлен/ий - тюлень/его

Но: весн/а – весен/н/ий – основа на Н  + суффикс Н, беглая Е, две буквы НН.

**2. Основа на Н и нулевой суффикс (одна буква Н)**

Ворон –  ворон/ой, один – един/ый, свинья – свин/ой (в последнем слове усечение основы сущ. на звук Й). Сравнить (та же схема образования): золот/о – золот/ой.

**3.** **Относительно-притяжательные прилагательных с суффиксом  ИН (одна буква Н):**

Лебедь – лебед/ин/ый, гусь - гус/ин/ый.

Но: холст – холст/ин/а – холст/ин/н/ый, овца – овч/ин/а – овч/ин/н/ый.  Здесь основа на ИН + суффикс Н, две буквы НН.

Comment: Не могли бы вы разъяснить следующее. В своём 2-х томном словообразовательном словаре в разделе "Как пользоваться словарём" Тихонов А.Н. пишет: "Все словообразовательные аффиксы выделены жирным шрифтом".  Теперь к слову "свиной". В слове свин-ин-(а), он выделяет жирным шрифтом суффикс -ин, а -а заключает в скобки, и здесь вопросов не возникает. А вот в слове свин-ой жирным шрифтом он выделяет -ой.

Comment: Таким образом, что это означает, что -ой это словообразовательный аффикс? Почему бы ему тогда не заключить в скобки -ой, а между основой и  -ой поставить знак нулевого суффикса. Я никак не могу ответить себе на этот вопрос.

Comment: Иван, да я посмотрела, у меня Школьный словарь 1978 года, там тоже ОЙ выделено жирным шрифтом, но что интересно, в слове золотой то же самое, хотя там вообще звука Й не было. Словообразование – темная наука (разное время, разные авторы, разные подходы), а еще есть понятие словообразовательных моделей.  Я пока не готова вам ответить, но вы задайте на форуме вопрос по этим двум словам (способ словообразования и морфемный анализ). У нас есть участники, которые интересуются словарями. А я подумаю. В Сети все дружно выделяют окончание ОЙ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы спрашиваете: *«Правильно ли я понимаю, что эти прилагательные надо запомнить, и их написание никак **больше не обосновывается, кроме как правилом с „йот“**?»*

> **Одна буква Н**
>
> Одна буква Н пишется в суффиксах -ан/-ян, -ын/-ин прилагательных,
> **образованных от имён существительных**: глиняный (< глина), журавлиный (< журавль), берестяной (< береста), комариный (< комар).
>
> Исключения: деревянный, стеклянный, оловянный.
>
> Примечания:
>
> **1. В прилагательных зелёный, свиной, бараний, синий, юный, единый и некоторых других звук [н] относится к
> корню.**
> …
> [[yaklass.ru](https://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/6-klass/imia-prilagatelnoe-10562/pravopisanie-imen-prilagatelnykh-10565/re-c6df7004-f7ee-4987-98d5-b00a7c4340e2)]

Слова: «бараний», «тюлений», «свиной», «вороний» и др. — это слова, образованные от имён существительных: *«бараний» < «баран»*, *«тюлений» < «тюлень»* и т. д. Именно поэтому одна буква «н». Эти слова подчиняются общему правилу. Не нужно их запоминать отдельно.

Из-за того, что они образованы при помощи суффикса «-j-» («йот»), а не «-ан/-ян», «-ын/-ин», звук [н] относится у них к корню, а не к суффиксу. Но это не является критерием написания одной или двух букв «н».

Например:

- «н» относится к корню существительного от которого образовано прилагательное: *«бараний» < «баран»*. В «баран» — уже есть буква «н» в конце корня и добавляется только суффикс “-ий” (“-j-”);
- а в *«журавлиный» < «журавль»* — буквы «н» в конце корня слова нет, тут добавляется суффикс «-ин»: *«журавл**ин**ый» < «журавль»*.
  Если бы добавлялось «-ин» к корню «баран», то произошло бы удвоение «н».

В приведенном вами правиле сказано:

> Прилагательные бараний, тюлений, свиной и подобные пишутся с одной н,
> так как они образованы от существительных с основой на н путем
> прибавления суффикса -j- (йот).

Тут объясняется почему при словообразовании, получилась одна буква «н», а не даётся критерий, по которому нужно отличать прилагательные с одним «н», от прилагательных с двумя «н».

Вы спрашиваете: *«Что значит путём прибавления суффикса -j- (йот)? Где в слове бараний, тюлений и свиной суффикс йот?»*

Суффикс «-j-» это «-ий», добавляющийся к корню существительного, от которого образовано прилагательное. Например: «баран» > «баран**ий**».

> С у ф ф и к с -и й/-|j|-. Прилагательные с суф. ­ий (фонемат. | α1j |;
> во всех формах, кроме им. п. ед. ч. муж. р., — с морфом ­| j |­),
> местоименного типа склонения (орфогр. — в им. п. на ­ий, -ья, -ье,
> -ьи: лисий, лисья, лисье, лисьи), **имеют значение «свойственный, присущий (реже — принадлежащий) тому, кто назван (что названо)
> мотивирующим словом»:** человечий, мужичий, казачий, вдовий, внучий,
> птичий, **бараний**, рыбий.
>
> [Н. Ю. ШВЕДОВА (главный редактор) Русская грамматика, том I Фонетика.
> Фонология. Ударение. Интонация. Введение в морфемику.
> Словообразование. Морфология]

Кроме того:

> В некоторых случаях суффикс -j- может не получать в слове специального
> графического обозначения. На его наличие могут указывать гласные е, ё,
> ю, я в положении после согласного или разделительный ь, например:
> Поволжь[ j ]е [пΛво́лжjь], Заонежь[ j ]е [зъΛн’э́жjь].
>
> [[licey.net](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/650-27_suffiksy_postfiksy.html)]

Если просклонять, например, «бараний» по падежам:

- бараний
- бараньего
- бараньему
- бараний
- бараньим
- бараньем

В словах: «бараньего», «бараньему» и «бараньем» — суффикс «‑j‑» не имеет графического обозначения, а на его наличие указывает гласная «е».

Answer (score 1):

> Слова «бараний», «тюлений», «свиной», «вороний» и др. Чем
> обосновывается написание одной «н»?

Обосновывается тем, что эти слова образованы добавлением к корню только окончания "ой/ий", без использования суффикса "н".

Сравните:
*рыбий* = *рыб + ий*.
*рыб**н**ый* = *рыб + н + ый*

*Рыбий* (наприм. *рыбий жир*) образован по такому же принципу, что и интересующие вас *бараний*, *тюлений*, *свиной*, то есть без суффикса *н*, а *рыбный* - с суффиксом *н*.

Чувствуете разницу в оттенке смысла? Про *рыбий* можно спросить "чей". А к слову *рыбный* вопрос "чей" как-то не подходит, только "какой".

То есть эти слова (образованные таким образом) имеют оттенок притяжательности (принадлежности).